# How to escape ' : ' using Ruby Gem Builder::XmlMarkup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, xml-parsing, rubygems

I'm a ruby beginner and I would need to create an xml doc out of a csv to send it out to one my supplier. 
I found the gem [Builder::XmlMarkup](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/activesupport/2.3.17/Builder/XmlMarkup) which is very useful. So far, my code looks like this:

```
    require 'csv'
    require 'builder'

    File.open("testXML.xml","w"){|f|
      builder = Builder::XmlMarkup.new(:target => f, :indent => 2)
      builder.instruct! :xml, :standalone=>"yes"

      csv = CSV.open('test.csv','rb',:headers=>true)
      csv2 = CSV.open('test.csv','rb',:headers=>true)

    builder.SupplierFile("xmlns:ns2"=>"http://impl.ws.tediber.com", "xmlns:ns1" =>
    "http://obj.ws.tediber.com", "xmlns:xsi"=>"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"){
      builder.Credit{#, "upgnr"=>"12345"
        builder.CreditList do |b|

          csv2.each do |csv|

          column = csv[0].split(",")

            builder.Refund("id"=>"#{column[0]}") do |b|
              builder.ns2:doCredit do |b|
                b.ns2invoiceID("#{column[0]}")
                builder.ns2:payment do |b|
                  b.ns1amount("#{column[2]}")
                  b.ns1currency("#{column[3]}")
                  b.ns1action("#{column[4]}")
                  b.ns1mode("#{column[5]}")
                  b.ns1contract("#{column[6]}")

                end
                b.ns2comment("#{column[7]}")
              end
            end
          end
        end

      }
    }
    }
```

However I would need an xml format like that with `<ns1:currency>`instead of `<ns1currency>`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<SupplierFile xmlns:ns2="http://impl.ws.tediber.com" xmlns:ns1="http://obj.ws.tediber.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Credit>
    <CreditList>
      <Refund id="10006144909513">
        <ns2:doCredit>
          <ns2:invoiceID>10006144539513</ns2:transactionID>
          <ns2:payment>
            <ns1:amount>8900</ns1:amount>
            <ns1:currency>978</ns1:currency>
            <ns1:action>8900</ns1:action>
            <ns1:mode>AAA</ns1:mode>
            <ns1:contract>HZW_1202</ns1:contractNumber>
          </ns2:payment>
          <ns2:comment>Invoice_EUR_10006144909513</ns2:comment>
        </ns2:doCredit>
      </Refund>
    </CreditList>
  </CreditList>
</SupplierFile>
```

When I try the following code, it doesn't work due to ":"

```
b.ns1:amount("#{column[2]}")
b.ns1:currency("#{column[3]}")
b.ns1:action("#{column[4]}")
b.ns1:mode("#{column[5]}")
b.ns1:contract("#{column[6]}")
```

I managed to get the xml but without the ":"

Is there a solution to add ":" into my code?

Comment: You can write `"#{column[2]}"` just as `column[2]`. There's no need to interpolate the value into a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [its documentation](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/activesupport/2.3.17/Builder/XmlMarkup), it looks like `Builder::XmlMarkup` allows you to define tags with unusual symbols using the `#tag!` method, which takes the tag name as a first argument.

Please see if this works:
`b.tag!("ns1:amount", "#{column[2]}")`.

edit: there seem to also be a simpler way of creating XML namespaces. You also need to provide two arguments for it, but in this way:

```rb
b.ns1(:amount, "#{column[2]}")
# or without parens:
b.ns1 :amount, "#{column[2]}"
```